# How to Assign a unique AUTO_INCREMENT Id to a user session

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the following code which generates an autoid from a table and assigns it to a session. The problem is when the same page is opened on 2 different computers it assigns the same ID to the user. Is there a way to assign a Unique Id to each session.

```
$sql = $link->query("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT AS mId FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'member_info'");
$data = $sql->fetch();
if(!empty($_SESSION['mId']))
{  
    $mId = $_SESSION['mId'];            
}
$mId =  $data['mId'];
echo $mId;
```

Comment: Because you aren't inserting anything, you're actually just getting the next auto increment ID that **would** identify the next inserted row.

Comment: Do an INSERT into member_info instead of fetching the auto_increment, and get the row id. It is the only way to reserve the ID so no one else will use it.

Comment: @AronCederholm If I do an Insert and the user close the browser, that I think will add an empty row in the database, isnt it?

Comment: @user580950 We don't know what your app is doing, only you do, but I can tell you that this isn't a valid way to get a unique identifier.

Comment: ... it's not valid because it's prone to race conditions to add to @Devon 's comment.